# Add Custom Link To A WordPress Theme Website

Tags: php, wordpress

I am using a `WordPress` theme - 123 Medicine to build a test website and it works as expected. But having a little issue that I am trying to resolve. In the website, I would like to include a div section that'll show the login as well the registration link on the top as follows I mean in the below I've given the demo link of the theme and the link should be above the search box:

[123 Medicine Theme](http://demo.lpd-themes.com/preview/?theme=123-Medicine)

Here is the test website link that I am working with - [Test Website](http://wponline.byethost7.com/PharmacyApp)

I've tried to include the div section as follows by myself in the index page but it doesn't show up. That's the below:

```
<div class="header-lh">
   You can <a href="#">login</a> or create <a href="#">an account</a>
</div>
```

I am not sure but is there any way I can add it to the top using dashboard or by myself manipulating the theme file?

**N.B**: This should be visible in the entire website, not only in the home page.

Comment: You need to check in backend theme options(Appearance >> Theme Options).There should be an option regarding login/registration(Especially in header settings) which may need to be enabled as Demo theme is showing it and your theme does not show.

Comment: Yes @Patrick R. I thought so and tried to do that but didn't get any option there. Any other alternative to do so?